# Simple Probability Notation

Tags: probability, notation, definition

A friend linked me a free online book, http://www.jiblm.org/downloads/dlitem.php?id=77&category=jiblmjournal, Chapter 4 - Probability, starts off by listing notations. But then, in the next set of questions, there appears to be a notation not listed or clarified. I don't want to assume it means something, that it very well might not.
$$
\overline{A \cup B}
$$

Because one of the definitions talked about $\overline{A}$ and defined it as being the elements found in $\Omega$, but not in A. At first I wanted to presume that the two were related in some fashion. Like it was just a different way to write $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$. But I can't figure out why the Overline would go over the Union. Then I saw this just a page or so later:
$$
\overline{ \overline{A} \cup B}
$$
And now I am confused and don't know what to think.
I tried to look through previous topics, but there doesn't appear to be a general or pinned topic that provides definitions for all of different notations.

I like how the book is structured. But I fear that there is some "lost in translation" with it.

I did try searching the site, but it seems that all of the other questions pertained to other notations. As a suggestion; perhaps making a pinned topic that discusses all the different notations, as a one-stop shop.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: If the sample space is $\Omega$ and $A \subset \Omega$, then $\bar A = \{ x \in \Omega \mid x \notin A \}$, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $C = A \cup B$. This is just some set. So we can think of its complement, $\overline{C} = \overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

So $\overline{A \cup B}$ is the everything that is not in $A$ and not in $B$.

Comment: So the Overline over the Union ... is the same as saying Intersect?
$\overline{\cup} = \cap$ ?

Comment: @HoushouRattengod You should read about [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @HoushouRattengod: Not really.  An overline just over the union or intersection symbol doesn't have any agreed-upon meaning.  You can think of the overline as providing both grouping (a la parentheses) and set complement.

Comment: I think I'm slowly understanding. $\overline{A \cup B}$ is basically a different way to write $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$. I presume the reasoning behind this has algebraic implications, no? Is it common for a person to convert it, to read & understand it properly? Or is that more for those learning the subject?

Comment: @HoushouRattengod In my mind, when I see $\overline{A \cup B}$, I think ,"This is the complement of $A \cup B$. In other words, it's the set of all elements of the sample space which do not belong to $A \cup B$." I also know that by De Morgan's laws $\overline{A \cup B}$ happens to be the same set as $\bar A \cap \bar B$, and I can see that almost directly because not belonging to $A$ or $B$ is the same thing as not belonging to $A$ and also not belonging to $B$. But that is not the first thing I think of.

Answer (score 1):

Something that helped me when I started learning set theory for probability was to make Venn Diagrams. $\overline{A \cup B}$ is the complement of $A \cup B$, so draw out what $A \cup B$ looks like and then take its complement. $\overline{A \cup B} = \{x \in \Omega | x\notin A , x\notin B\}$

Comment: If we use the example given in the book:
$\Omega = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,910}  A = {1,2,3,4,5}  B = {2,4,6,8,10}$

$\overline{A \cup B} = {7,9}$ ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Note that in the answer by @Rishi $\overline{A \cup B}=\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, which is the same as the set I indicated above.